# Deleting Old Nuget Package Folders after upgrading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, packages, package-managers

Should you delete the old Nuget package files/folders under the packages directory after you upgrade a package?

Maybe I'm just being overly picky, but seeing files/folder for older package versions it bothering me.  Is there a good reason NOT to delete the package folders for previous package versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NuGet should remove old versions when upgrading, without any specific user intervention. If, for some reason, the old versions still exist after upgrade then they're safe to remove since there's no reason to keep them there.

I'm assuming that the upgrade is done through `update-package` command.